# Technique to iterative functional equations $f_{(r)}(x)=2^{(\log x)^c}$ and $g_{(r)}(x)=2^{x^\frac{1}{c}}$

Tags: functional-equations

What is function $f,g:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R$ sought that satisfies $$\forall x\in\mathbb N,\,f_{(r)}(x)=\underbrace{f(f(\dots(f(f(x)))\dots))}_{r\text{ times}}=2^{(\log x)^c}$$
$$\forall x\in\mathbb N,\,g_{(r)}(x)=\underbrace{g(g(\dots(g(g(x)))\dots))}_{r\text{ times}}=2^{x^\frac{1}{c}}$$
where $c>0$ is fixed?

What is solution if above relations hold at every $x\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: Where does this come from, and have you done any work or have any ideas yourself?

Comment: What is $k$? I don't see $k$ in your equation. Do you mean $r$?

Comment: The domain of $f$ is not correct. Notice that $f(-1)$ is not defined. Actually, you should have $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Actually, the domain of $f$ can be defined in $\mathbb{R}^+$. However, the expression is evaluated only in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @AlexSilva corrected mistake.

Comment: I think question is settled. domain of interest is $\Bbb N$ however domain is $\Bbb R^+$. I think if it works over $\Bbb N$, it will work over $\Bbb R^+$.

Answer (score 1):

With
$$
u(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
1 & {\small\mbox{for }} x = 0 \\
0 & {\small\mbox{for }} x \ne 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

We define
\begin{align}
f(x) 
&= \left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{(\log k)^c} u(x-k) \right] + 
x \left[ 1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty u(x-k)\right] \\
&= x + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(2^{(\log k)^c} - x\right) u(x-k)
\end{align}

then for $n \in\mathbb{N}$
$$
f(n) = 2^{(\log n)^c} \quad (*)
$$

and for $x \not\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
f(x) = x
$$
For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ this gives
$$
f_{(r)}(n) = f^{r}(n) = f^{r-1}(f(n)) = f^{r-1}(2^{(\log n)^c}) = 2^{(\log n)^c}
$$
The construction relies mostly ($n=1$ gives $f(1) = 1$) on the assumption that natural numbers do not get mapped to natural numbers in equation $(*)$.

The shorter version would be
$$
f(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
2^{(\log x)^c} & {\small\mbox{for }} x \in\mathbb{N} \\
x & {\small\mbox{for }} x \not\in\mathbb{N}
\end{array}
\right.
$$